# Do lightsabers have safety settings?

Tags: star-wars

While rewatching *Star Wars* my skin was crawling while watching Luke practice saber technique against a remote on the *Falcon*.  There's no way I'd want to be in the same room with a beginner waving a lightsaber around, let alone a beginner with his eyes covered.

Samurai apparently practiced with [*bokken*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokken) to reduce training injuries.  **Do lightsabers have lower power settings so that a wrong move while practicing doesn't sever a limb or chop through the hull into vacuum?**

Comment: Ah. And I found that we have covered this question before.

Comment: I get the same feeling when Obi-Wan first hands a light saber to Luke *without explaining what it is.*

Comment: Relevant: http://cdn.themetapicture.com/media/funny-Luke-Skywalker-lightsaber.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for a [training lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Training_lightsaber). They boast a stronger containment field so that the weapon can bruise at best. According to the Star Wars wikia entry, they are adjustable to be able to do more damage, but presumably it requires someone with a fair degree of knowledge to disable the safety interlocks.

Comment: That said, the sabre used in the practice session on the _Millennium Falcon_ wasn't one.

Comment: Jacen Solo & Tenel Ka learned the hard way why you should always practice with a training saber.

Comment: Since we see training lightsabers in the prequel movies, I assume that they're still canon under Disney...

Comment: Taking all this into account No.  But I assume that Obi- Wan didn't really tell Luke much first when he received the lightsaber under the assumption that Luke (having lifted on the frontier) wouldn't go pressing buttons on things that look like weapons, after which Luke figured it out ignited it and then Obi-wan explained.  We can also assume that Obi-wan accepted  and then warned Luke of the potential risks of using a lightsaber for training.