Do non-lethal 'practice' lightsabers exist?
By 'practice lightsabers' I mean a kind that, on striking a student would be felt and maybe even cause a bruise but not actually maim or kill (the same principle as wooden 'dummy-blades' that were used to teach swordsmanship in real life). Do such teaching tools exist in Star Wars?

I don't have most of these sources to chase down direct quotes, so this is just a comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Training_lightsaber

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218512/were-the-lightsabers-used-by-younglings-different-from-the-regular-lightsabers-u https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83211/do-lightsabers-have-safety-settings

I'm currently reading a Legends book which has some kind of training sabre... If you are okay to accept Legends, then I could try and get more detail.

@HorusKol- sure, but since they closed the question I'm not sure what good it'll do.
